# Category Description (number) calculate

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a Wordpress installation for a restaurant, with a menu (food) with numbers.

The menu (food) numbers dosn't go from 1-50 continuously but starts with the next 5 like this:

Lunch offers: 1-4
Chicken sticks: 10-13
Chicken wings: 15-17
Salads: 20-23

This is made, so it's easy to add something within the different categories without the following menues would have to change the number.

However, this is very hard (for me at least) to make.

My solution is to give every category a number, in the description, and then add this number to the childs number of the category.

Ex.:
Lunch offers (categoryDesc. = 1)
- (menuNumber = categoryDesc + ChildNo) Burger (childNo = 1)
- (menuNumber = categoryDesc + ChildNo) Chicken (childNo = 2)
- (menuNumber = categoryDesc + ChildNo) Salad (childNo = 3)

Does it make sense? If so, how do I achieve this?

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to make the list with ordered lists (OL) and then start the OL's with the number you want to.

```
<ol start="5">
    <li>This is number 5</li>
    <li>This is number 6</li>
    <li>This is number 7</li>
</ol>
```

That's the way I did it.